# How remove spacing Horizontal GridLayoutManager recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, spacing, gridlayoutmanager

I use recyclerview with grid layoutmanager
I don't add ItemDecoration

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(TestResultActivity.this, 4, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            gridLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
            grid.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

But between two rows, have a row and I don't add it. I want to remove it.

[image]